# Android EditText.setText() is not updating the Layout, but the EditText has changed

Tags: android, android-layout

So, what is happening is that the EditText won't update. The value has updated, but the value isn't being shown on the screen. In my app, I'm switching layouts a lot, and I'm needing to save the EditText values of the previous layout, to be restored on switching back. This is what I'm doing:

When switching from:

```
exampleEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.exampleedittext);
exampleEditTextString = exampleEditText.getText().toString();
setContentView(R.layout.secondLayout)
```

When switching back:

```
setContentView(R.layout.originalLayout)
exampleEditText.setText(exampleEditTextString);
```

I'm logging the exampleEditTextString, and then the exampleEditText.getText().toString(); and the values are the same, but it's not displaying on the screen that way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In what method are you doing this?

Comment: In a button's onClick method

Comment: Do you do this in only one Activity, or many?

Comment: I'm doing it in the MainActivity.

Comment: when you say you change layout, Are you starting a new activity and then coming back to previous activity? Please edit your question and post your code.

Comment: You might need to do another `findViewById` after called `setContentView` again.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I think it isn't refreshing, since if I check the value in the logcat, it is displaying correctly there.

Comment: Wait, findViewById again does seem to work. I just didn't do it correctly I guess. If you want to, post it as an answer and I can accept it.

Comment: Don't do that. Either use fragments or seperate activities

Comment: Update your UI in onResume().

Answer (score 0):

If you are switching between activities, you need to add

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

to your manifest file to prevent the onCreate method each time you start a new activity.

Below is part of the manifest file

```
<application
    ...
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
```